# R asks for a list which seems to be a list according to is.list (=TRUE)

Tags: r, list, input, dataframe, formatting

I am using the RAM package.
The function I use is very simple for diversity index, adding up a column in my metadata ;

```
outname <-OTU.diversity(data=OTUtables, meta=metatables)
```

> (Arguments:  data a list of OTU tables.
>
> meta   the metadata to append the outputs)

I am looping it but I get this error:

> *please provide otu tables as list; see ?RAM.input.formatting*

So I go to that help menu and read this:

> one data set:
>
> ```
> data=list(data=otu)
> ```
>
> multiple data sets:
>
> ```
> data=list(data1=otu1, data2=otu2, data3=otu3)
> ```

here is my code:

```
i <- 1

for(i in 1:nrow(metadataMasterTax)){
  temp <-  read.table(paste(metadataMasterTax$DataAnFilePath[i], metadataMasterTax$meta[i], sep = ""),
                      sep = "\t", header = TRUE, dec = ".", comment.char = "", quote = "", stringsAsFactors = TRUE,
                      as.is = TRUE)
  temp2 <- temp
  temp2$row.names <- NULL #to unactivate numbers generated in the margin

  trans <-  read.table(paste(metadataMasterTax$taxPath[i], metadataMasterTax$taxName[i], sep = ""),
                      sep = "\t", header = TRUE, dec = ".", comment.char = "", quote = "", stringsAsFactors = TRUE,
                      as.is = TRUE, check.names = FALSE)
  trans2 <- trans
  trans2$row.names <- NULL #to unactivate numbers generated in the margin

  data=list(data=trans2[i])

  temp2[i] <- OTU.diversity(data=trans2[i], meta=temp2[i])

 # Error in OTU.diversity(trans2, temp2) : 
 # please provide otu tables as list; see ?RAM.input.formatting
 # is.list(trans2)
 # [1] TRUE
 # is.list(data)
 # [1] TRUE

  temp$taxonomy <- temp2$taxonomy

  write.table(temp, file=paste(pathDataAn, "diversityDir/", metadataMasterTax$ShortName[i], ".meta.div.tsv", sep = ""),
              append    = FALSE,
              sep       = "\t",
              row.names = FALSE)
}
```

Can anyone help me please....
thanks a lot

Comment: So why didn't you do what the help page said? You are not passing your list to the function. Try `data=list(data=trans2); temp2 <- OTU.diversity(data=data, meta=temp2)` (not sure what you were trying to accomplish with the `[i]`, are you trying to store the result for each iteration, if you you'd need to predefine a list and use `[[i]]` to put such an object into it. But that's a separate issue I guess)

Comment: The help page says to pass a list but is.list gives a TRUE return and so I am confused. I tried without the [i] options too before and I get the same erre

Comment: Don't use is.list(). That's misleading. You are passing a data.frame which internal is stored as a list but isn't the kind of list they are talking about.

Comment: Also, I did try your function too before posting and no luck either. It might sound like I posted at first issue I encoutered but I did try all afternoon using different combinations.

Comment: Ok so might you please explain the type of list I need. Thanks

Comment: Well you code relies on data files that we don't have access to so we can't test any possible solutions or recreate the error. It would be better if you made a more reproducible example. Use built-in data sets to make it easier to help.

Comment: I do want separate output tables in the end which is why I tried the [i] options.

Comment: I will have access to my data in the morning. If that helps now I use a table with my file names & paths listed. I call them from there. I used it for another looped function.

Comment: when I run the data=list(data=trans2) it adds-up ''data.." infront of my headers name and a "." after the headers name. That cause issue with the function then. 

ok here is a link for a metadata file, an OTU file and the table with sample info.

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B8zzlTlIlR2BQlhoVWlYNEZXTnc&usp=sharing

Comment: Can you clarify `temp$taxonomy <- temp2$taxonomy`?  As far as I can tell,  `temp2` does not contain the column `taxonomy`.  What is `temp` (the object in your `write.table` function) supposed to look like?

Comment: Sorry, a copy/paste mistake of mine. It should be  temp$diversity <- temp2$diversity so that a column (last column in meta table) called diversity is added(created, you are right it i snot there yet) with the values of diversity indexes gotten for each sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the main problem appears to be getting the `OTU.diversity` function to work, I focus on this issue.  The code snippet below runs `OTU.diversity` without any problems, using the Google sheets data provided by OP.

```
library(gsheet)
library(RAM)

for (i in 1:2) {
  # Meta data
  temp <- as.data.frame(gsheet2tbl("https://drive.google.com/open?id=1hF47MbYZ1MG6RzGW-fF6tbMT3z4AxbGN5sAOxL4E8xM"))
  temp$row.names <- NULL

  # OTU
  trans <- as.data.frame(gsheet2tbl("https://drive.google.com/open?id=1gOaEjDcs58T8v1GA-OKhnUsyRDU8Jxt2lQZuPWo6XWU"))
  trans$row.names <- NULL

  rownames(temp) <- colnames(trans)[-ncol(trans)]

  temp2 <- OTU.diversity(data = list(data = trans), meta = temp)

  write.table(temp2, 
              file      = paste0("file", i, ".meta.div.tsv"), # replace 
              append    = FALSE,
              sep       = "\t",
              row.names = FALSE)
}
```

Replace `for (i in 1:2)` with `for(i in 1:nrow(metadataMasterTax))`, `as.data.frame(gsheet2tbl(...))` with `read.table(...)`, and the `file` argument in `write.table` with the appropriate string.

Comment: ok what is this for
rownames(temp) <- colnames(trans)[-ncol(trans)]

Comment: because it has a bug at that line....
Error in `row.names<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = value) : 
  invalid 'row.names' length

Comment: Hi, I just rebooted everything and guess what: it worked all of a sudden.